# Curl post request fails - bugs in a script or blocked?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to post a request to http://iate.europa.eu/ using the following script:

```
     <?php

$output_array = array();

$post = "method=search&saveStats=true&screenSize=1920x1080&query=bond&valid=Szukaj+&sourceLanguage=en&targetLanguages=pl&domain=&domain=12&typeOfSearch=s&request=";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://iate.europa.eu/SearchByQueryEdit.do');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

echo $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

?>
```

The data I used:
[image]

When I run the script, I get "Access Denied. Your request has been denied for security reason."

Does the script trigger some security mechansims or does it simply make bad requests?

Thx in advance,

Lukasz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added an agent. Try this:

```
$post = "method=search&saveStats=true&screenSize=1920x1080&query=bond&valid=Szukaj+&sourceLanguage=en&targetLanguages=pl&domain=&domain=12&typeOfSearch=s&request=";

$ch = curl_init();

/* Additional Code Start */
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:30.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/30.0";        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
/* Additional Code End*/

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://iate.europa.eu/SearchByQueryEdit.do');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

echo $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks. The script gets the data, but not the data I want. It just echoes the start page. Could you look into the http://iate.europa.eu/ and my '$post' variable?

Comment: Do you still need help? I can detailed look for the problem tomorrow.